# Inline escaping {{ myVariable }}

Tags: listings

How to escape Mustache notation inline for example:
This is a Mustache placeholder `{{ myVariable }}` that will output `myVariable`.

This seems to be causing errors:

```
\lstinline{ {{#if}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}} }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a different delimiter to denote the start-and-end of your code snippet, similar to what is requested when using `\verb`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

Here is some Java:
\lstinline!{{#if}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}!

\end{document}
```

Above the delimiter `!` denotes the start-and-end of the code snippet, since I don't use `!` within the code itself.

Related, but not really the cause: Page 27 of the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) mentions this about using `\lstinline`:

> An experimental implementation has been done to support the syntax
>   `\lstinline[<key=value list>]{<source code>}`. Try it if you want and report
>   success and failure.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Took me hours to get nowhere. I know reading documentation per each package is a good start.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply! 
Works as a charm, also code coloring and formatting is okay, well I'll have to add some more keywords. Took me hours to get nowhere. I know reading documentation per each package is a good start, but I am heavily skip reading. 
Perhaps defining a separate \lstdefinelanguage{Mustache} is something I need to consider.

Comment: @ErikUšaj: Yes, you can define your own language style. If this answered your question, consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) as such.